# Add items to ICollection

Tags: c#, icollection

I defined an ICollection as

```
 public virtual ICollection<Attempt> Attempts { get; set; }
```

And `Attempt` is defined as

```
 public class Attempt
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string AttemptsMetaData { get; set; }
     public DateTime Time { get; set; }
     public bool Answered { get; set; }
     public DateTime Disconnected { get; set; }
 }
```

Now I want to pass ICollection to a method.

```
public void AddTask(ICollection<Attempt> attempts)
{
    // Do something to the item in attempts.
}
```

Now I have to create a sample data to this collection. I am not sure how. The code below maybe wrong.
What I thought was

```
        // test data
        Guid id = new Guid();
        string attempt = "test";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        bool answered = true;
        DateTime disconnected = DateTime.Now;
        ICollection <Attempt> attempts= new List<Attempt>();
        // try to add sample data to the list
```

Comment: ICollection is a more abstract interface. Prefer IEnumerable for these kinda scenarios.

Comment: create instance of Attempt, set properties values, and call attempsts.Add(your instance goes here);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Attempt> attempts= new List<Attempt>();
//Create a Instance of Attempt
Attempt objAtt = new Attempt();
Guid id = new Guid();
objtAtt.Id =id;
objtAtt.Time = DateTime.Now;
objAtt.AttemptsMetaData ="test";
objAtt.Answered = true;
objAtt.Disconnected = DateTime.Now;
attempts.Add(objAtt);
```

Here you pass to method,

```
AddTask(attempts);
```

Your method like this,

```
public void AddTask(List<Attempt> attempts)
{

}
```

Comment: Then how to pass it to AddTask(ICollection attempts)?

Comment: @love check modified answer

Comment: @Love - You can pass the list that you have. Being a base interface, it accepts the list.

Comment: So you mean I have to change the method AddTask to List? Can we just keep it as ICollection and pass a List object?

Answer (score 0):

```
var attempt = new Attempt(/*whatever here*/);

attempts.Add(attempt);

AddTask(attempts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this :

```
 public void AddTask(Attempt objAtempt)
    {
        List<Attempt> attempts = new List<Attempt>();
        objAtempt.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        objAtempt.Time = DateTime.Now;
        objAtempt.AttemptsMetaData = "test";
        objAtempt.Answered = true;
        objAtempt.Disconnected = DateTime.Now;
        attempts.Add(objAtempt);
    }
```